Kerberos: KDC returned error string: NO PREAUTH
I have installed a Kerberos server on Debian Bookworm:
krb5-kdc/stable-security,now 1.20.1-2+deb12u2
krb5-kdc-ldap/stable-security,now 1.20.1-2+deb12u2
krb5-pkinit/stable-security,now 1.20.1-2+deb12u2
krb5-user/stable-security,now 1.20.1-2+deb12u2

SSH authentication to any host on my network is working smoothly using GSSAPI and Kerberos. No problems so far.
However, when trying to login via SSH to the Kerberos server itself I cannot get this to work, and I am not sure what is the problem here.
This is what ssh -vvv ns01 says on login attempt to the Kerberos server itself from another host (this case 192.168.10.7):
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
KDC returned error string: NO PREAUTH

And krb5kdc Debug log on server when trying to login:
Aug 09 09:08:51 ns01.example.com krb5kdc[4557](info): TGS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 192.168.10.7: NO PREAUTH: authtime 0, etypes {rep=UNSUPPORTED:(0)} user@example.com for host/ns01.example.com@example.com, Generic error (see e-text)

When doing a remote login to another server within the network, this is what krb5kdc logs in this case (successful):
Aug 09 09:10:39 ns01.example.com krb5kdc[4557](info): TGS_REQ (1 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18)}) 192.168.10.7: ISSUE: authtime 1723186107, etypes {rep=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), tkt=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), ses=aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18)}, user@example.com for krbtgt/example.com@example.com

The keytab on the server itself is like any other remote ssh host:
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   4 09.08.2024 08:16:50 host/ns01.example.com@webtux.de (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 
   4 09.08.2024 08:16:50 host/ns01.example.com@webtux.de (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96) 

Any ideas how to debug this further?

Can you show the kadmin getprinc flags for both the user principal and the service principal? (...and for the krbtgt principal just in case.)

Your client principal is most probably missing the requires_pre_auth flag.
Traditionally Kerberos would issue TGTs without any authentication, relying solely on the fact that they are encrypted with the client's password. But this makes them vulnerable to offline password brute-force attacks (the fancy AD people call it "ASREP-roasting"), so pre-authentication was added in Kerberos 5 to require the client to prove that it knows the password before it can get a TGT.
Pre-authentication is, however, optional and the MIT KDC only requires it for principals that have the aforementioned flag set. (For example, keytab-based principals usually don't need preauth because they have randomized keys that are infeasible to crack anyway.)
Kerberos treats it a little bit like a policy feature – when you kinit, your TGT gets the P flag to indicate that preauth has taken place, and the KDC or services may use it to make access decisions (much like modern SSO systems may differentiate "logged in using a certificate" from "logged in using a password").
In fact, when a service principal has requires_pre_auth set – which would normally be no-op as services don't acquire TGTs – the MIT KDC will instead treat it as a requirement for the client of that service to be strengthened using preauth. If your user principal doesn't have the preauth flag and you kinit without preauth, then you are not allowed to get tickets for any service that has the preauth flag.
So you should modprinc all user account principals to ensure that they have preauth enabled (both for this problem and for security in general), and should perhaps add it to default_principal_flags in your kdc.conf. (Note that MIT Krb5 is highly inconsistent in the spelling of flag names; kadmin and kdc.conf expect different inputs.) After this, you must kinit again; then check which flags are shown by klist -f.
(As for the host & service principals – they don't strictly need the preauth flag, whether they also happen to act as clients or not, but it won't hurt anything to keep it enabled either; indeed it might help you catch future situations where a user somehow has preauth disabled again.)

Great answer so far, getting more into this preauth thing now :)
My user was as you said missing the requires_pre_auth flag. I have added it as you suggested and now it starts working on ns01 host.
However I do not understand why it was working on other hosts before?
"default_principal_flags = +preauth" is only necessary in the krb-server's krb5.conf, right?

It was probably working because your service principals (the host/* principals that you were connecting to) did not have this flag, except for the latest one which most likely does. [See part in bold.]

I see.. I think you are right here, thank you very much. I marked this post as solved
